# how to remove blank spaces when database data is printed on screen - PHP

Tags: php

Hi I have the following code. When the data is displayed on the screen blank areas are also printed. How can I adjust/change my code to eliminate blank spaces when records are displayed. Thanks you.

```
        <?php

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!");
$db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the database");
$SQLa="SELECT * FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk='$distUsr'";
$runa=mysql_query($SQLa,$con) or die ("SQL Error");
$nora=mysql_num_rows($runa);

echo "<table cellpadding='2' class='tablet' cellspacing='0'>";
echo 
"<tr>"
."<th>"."Starting Cheque No"."</th>"
."<th>"."Ending Cheque No"."</th>"
."<th>"."Total No of Cheques"."</th>"
."</tr>";

    while ($reca = mysql_fetch_array($runa))
    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$reca["sbstart"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$reca["sbend"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$reca["totsb"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: You are using [an obsolete database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068)

Comment: Well, you could _check_ if the fields are blank and don't display them in that case, or simply filter them out in your query. Are you really asking for a tutorial in basic conditional statements and `WHERE` conditions?

Comment: Is the PHP generating the HTML you expect, but the HTML is giving you the blank areas? If so, show us the HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Is the PHP generating HTML that isn't the way you want it, and the differences between how you want the HTML and how the HTML is are causing the blank areas? If so, show us the HTML and the PHP and tell us what is wrong with the source, not the rendering.

Comment: @Quentin What I meant by 'Blank areas' are the black spaces in the SQL database. So If one row has no data,once the data is displayed space is also printed and then the next row's data. So in a sequence I get data and blank spaces displayed. Hope this clarifies. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 while ($reca = mysql_fetch_array($runa))
    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".trim($reca["sbstart"])."</td>";
        echo "<td>".trim($reca["sbend"])."</td>";
        echo "<td>".trim($reca["totsb"])."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't properly understand what did you want to say but if you didn't want to print blank records then use this
**Use one of condition Either first or Second**

```
     while ($reca = mysql_fetch_array($runa))
        { 
            if($reca["sbstart"] || $reca["sbstart"] || $reca["sbstart"]){  //If any of record is empty
            echo "";
            echo "".$reca["sbstart"]."";
            echo "".$reca["sbend"]."";
            echo "".$reca["totsb"]."";
            echo "";
            }
           if($reca["sbstart"] && $reca["sbstart"] && $reca["sbstart"]){  //If all of row in record is empty
            echo "";
            echo "".$reca["sbstart"]."";
            echo "".$reca["sbend"]."";
            echo "".$reca["totsb"]."";
            echo "";
            }
        }
```

Or if you want to trim spaces then use this

```
     while ($reca = mysql_fetch_array($runa))
        {

            echo "";
            echo "".trim($reca["sbstart"])."";
            echo "".trim($reca["sbend"])."";
            echo "".trim($reca["totsb"])."";
            echo "";
        }
```

**I advice you to use mysqli_* or pdo instead of mysql_* as it is deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the function below,

```
function fetch_value($string) 
{    
        $string = trim($string);
        $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
        $string = stripslashes($string);
        return $string;
}
```

this will help us to remove white spaces as well as help u to stop sql injection as well.